# argmax in Spark DataFrames: how to retrieve the row with the maximum value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a Spark DataFrame `df`, I want to find the maximum value in a certain numeric column `'values'`, and obtain the row(s) where that value was reached. I can of course do this:

```py
# it doesn't matter if I use scala or python, 
# since I hope I get this done with DataFrame API
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
max_value = df.select(F.max('values')).collect()[0][0]
df.filter(df.values == max_value).show()
```

but this is inefficient since it requires two passes through `df`.

`pandas.Series`/`DataFrame` and `numpy.array` have `argmax`/`idxmax` methods that do this efficiently (in one pass). So does standard python (built-in function `max` accepts a key parameter, so it can be used to find the index of the highest value).

What is the right approach in Spark? Note that I don't mind whether I get all the rows that where the maximum value is achieved, or just some arbitrary (non-empty!) subset of those rows.

Comment: In general there is no better solution which is cross-language and can work on arbitrary data.

Comment: @zero323 why is it impossible to wrap the RDD code in the answer below in a DataFrame API, by converting it to Scala and adding proper metadata for Catalyst to work on?

Comment: It is possible but it clearly breaks the assumption that _it doesn't matter if you use Scala or Python_ You can also do it with Orderable data types with SQL alone but this is a special case not general solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If schema [is `Orderable`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d6dc12ef0146ae409834c78737c116050961f350/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ordering.scala#L89-L96) (schema contains only atomics / arrays of atomics / recursively orderable structs) you can use simple aggregations:

**Python**:

```py
df.select(F.max(
    F.struct("values", *(x for x in df.columns if x != "values"))
)).first()
```

**Scala**:

```scala
df.select(max(struct(
    $"values" +: df.columns.collect {case x if x!= "values" => col(x)}: _*
))).first
```

Otherwise you can reduce over `Dataset` (Scala only) but it requires additional deserialization:

```scala
type T = ???

df.reduce((a, b) => if (a.getAs[T]("values") > b.getAs[T]("values")) a else b)
```

You can also `oredrBy` and `limit(1)` / `take(1)`:

**Scala**:

```scala
df.orderBy(desc("values")).limit(1)
// or
df.orderBy(desc("values")).take(1)
```

**Python**:

```py
df.orderBy(F.desc('values')).limit(1)
# or
df.orderBy(F.desc("values")).take(1)
```

Comment: Do you mind linking to an explanation/definition of `Orderable` schema? Google search only found this very answer :)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d6dc12ef0146ae409834c78737c116050961f350/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ordering.scala#L89-L96

Comment: F is alias from: `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` for anyone else who reads problem title, then the answer and misses question context!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's an incomplete answer but you can use `DataFrame`'s internal `RDD`,  apply the `max` method and get the maximum record using a determined key.

```py
a = sc.parallelize([
    ("a", 1, 100),
    ("b", 2, 120),
    ("c", 10, 1000),
    ("d", 14, 1000)
  ]).toDF(["name", "id", "salary"])

a.rdd.max(key=lambda x: x["salary"]) # Row(name=u'c', id=10, salary=1000)
```

Comment: Can I assume 1 pass with RDD API (Scala to avoid python overhead) is guaranteed faster than 2 passes with DataFrame API? Or there's some optimization Catalyst could do here?